# Cannot post data from jQuery in Flask user Sign in button

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I'm building a flask app with user sign up button and want to check if it works well but no values return after clicking the button.

[image]

I add a jQuery POST request when the user clicks the Sign Up button.
Here is the **btnSignUp** in **signup.js** under **\static\js** folder:

```
   $(function(){
        $('#btnSignUp').click( function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "/signUp",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
   });
 });
```

Then simply check if they are valid and for the time being let's just return a simple message, here is the code in the **app.py**:

```
 @app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST'])
 def signUp():

     # read the posted values from the UI
     _name = request.form['inputName']
     _email = request.form['inputEmail']
     _password = request.form['inputPassword']

     # validate the received values
     if _name and _email and _password:
        return json.dumps({'html':'<span>All fields good !!</span>'})
     else:
        return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})
```

And finally is the sign up interface, **signup.html**:

```
  <h1>Register</h1>
    <form class="form-signin">
    <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
    <input type="name" name="inputName" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Sign up</button> </form>
```

I've also checked if the jQuery is correctly downloaded and placed:

[image]

And below is my python console, there is no "POST" after clicking the sign up button many times:

[image]

Kindly advise if any there is any issues, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding these 2 lines of code in **signup.html** solve the issue.

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/signup.js"></script>
```